# How to download large files on Windows server from Telegram bot using C# (greater 20MB)

Tags: c#, download, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using this code below but it works only for files under 20 MB, but I know other Telegram bots who bypass this limitation! For example look at [@attachbot](https://t.me/attachbot). It is in Persian language, if you do not know Persian just send a file first, then send a text. It gives you the result and there is a hidden link inside text which causes that image or video preview under the text. So it uses a URL for that large file! So it somehow saved that file on a server and now has a URL to access that large file.

```
string fileID = up.Message.Video.FileId;

var filePath = bot.GetFileAsync(fileID);

download_url = @"https://api.telegram.org/file/bot" + Token + "/" + filePath.Result.FilePath;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(download_url), @"D:\myFolder\aFileName.mp4");
}
```